# How do I make an expandable ad with FlashCC and CreateJS?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, createjs

I wonder if I make a Flash HTML5 Canvas Banner at 300x250 to start, how can I make it expand down the page and extend the canvas size?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var originalHeight = this.stage.canvas.height;
var expandedHeight = 300;  // Put here your desired height
this.stage.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOverHandle);

function mouseOverHandle() {

    this.stage.canvas.height = expandedHeight;
    this.stage.addEventListener("mouseleave", mouseLeaveHandle);
    this.stage.removeEventListener("mouseover", mouseOverHandle);
}
function mouseLeaveHandle() {
    this.stage.canvas.height = originalHeight;
    this.stage.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOverHandle);
    this.stage.removeEventListener("mouseleave", mouseLeaveHandle);
}
```

You will see some flickering, because the canvas redraw their content on resize. See this question for more info [Flickering during resizing of HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799564/flickering-during-resizing-of-html5-canvas)

Comment: Since the EaselJS display list is retained, you can get around a flickering canvas in EaselJS by just calling `stage.update` after the resize. http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/n9p7aL77/

Answer (score -1):

**Click on the canvas then there properties tab and FPS ,Size in then change size to if you want  size**

Comment: The question was how to extend the final banner, not the canvas in the IDE.