# Resize event causes uintended problem on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, resize

i'm trying to make ping pong game by using vanilla js,but i have came across an issue which is really annoying.The problem is whenever i resize the browser bats are flicking(they're displayed and disappeared quickly).

js code:

```
import {update} from './update.js'
import {draw} from './draw.js'

//Take pong field element
const PONG_FIELD_EL =document.getElementById('pongField');

//Call getContext api on the field el
const CTX = PONG_FIELD_EL.getContext('2d');

//Set width & height of the field equal to window's dimension initially
PONG_FIELD_EL.width = window.innerWidth;
PONG_FIELD_EL.height = window.innerHeight;

//Set width & height of the field equal to window's dimension on resizing
window.addEventListener('resize',()=>{
    PONG_FIELD_EL.width = window.innerWidth;
    PONG_FIELD_EL.height = window.innerHeight;
    
    gameLoop()
})

//Specify velocity 
const VELOCITY = 100;

//Define gameLoop func
function gameLoop(){
    //Call draw function
    draw(CTX)

    //Call update function
    update()
}


//Call gameLoop each time based on velocity
setInterval(()=>{
    gameLoop()
},VELOCITY)
```

The reason i have called gameLoop function within resize handler because i wanted to prevent bats from scaling on resizing.
if someone could help me with this i'd be really appreciate it.Hope that i could explain my problem clearly.

Comment: Does this post answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799564/flickering-during-resizing-of-html5-canvas

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I looked it up but couldn't figure out any solution to my problem yet.

Comment: It's kind of hard to know what's going on without the actual draw/update code. Are you sure that this `slider.onchange` function with the creation of a new context when resized doesn't help like in the posts's answer jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/Uz5Pt/13

Comment: Finally i could solve the problem.Thank you dude for taking your time.